# Firebase tools: login as service account

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I cannot find way how to deploy firebase project (functions) on behalf of service account.

Nothing is said both on [documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/) and also I found nothing related in their [bug tracker](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/).

As described, I run `firebase login:ci` command but then I need to login myself - and I want login as service account.

Such feature is available using `gcloud` tool, but, as stated in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/functions-and-firebase),

> Cloud Functions written using the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions can't be deployed using the gcloud command-line tool, and vice-versa.

Comment: Since the documentation explicitly says that this isn't possible, what is your question?

Comment: Documentation says that it is impossible use **gcloud** tool to deploy cloud functions written using firebase SDK. It doesn't say that deployment using firebase-tools on behalf of service account is impossible. I hope there should be some way

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Since [version 7.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.1.0) of the Firebase CLI/tools it **is** possible to authenticate with a service account.

Also see Michael's answer here: [Login to firebase using gcloud service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053919/login-to-firebase-using-gcloud-service-account)

Previous answer:

<strike>To use the Firebase CLI/tools you need to be signed in as an actual user. There is no way to run the Firebase CLI as a service account.</strike>

It's been noted as a valid and interesting feature request though! Some work that might help towards this feature is being done in [this PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/417/files). As usual: no commits on if/when/how this may land. Keep an eye on the [release notes](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases) for the latest updates.

Comment: It would be a useful feature.  We'd like to have our CI automatically deploy to firebase (hosting and functions) after successful builds and a service account seems like the sensible way to do that.

Comment: Looks like this is merged.

Comment: But what does it entitle for the service accounts login?

Comment: It seems something is happening there ... https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/787 Hopefully we'll have working GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS method soon :)

Comment: There is a PR for this feature: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/1463

Comment: I've tested the new Firebase CLI v7.1.0 with a service account and it works like a charm now: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.1.0

Comment: @Ani does authentication with service account work without needing a browser sign in step?

Comment: @Dapp Yes, it works without needing a browser sign in step. Since v7.1.0 we are able to use Firebase CLI to deploy Firestore and Storage rules as build-steps in CI/CD pipeline just using the default service account of Cloud Build (basically just like we use `gcloud`, `bq`, or `gsutil` there). But same should work also on Gitlab, Bitbucket CI etc with credentials of a custom service account.

Comment: @Ani To authenticate with a service account, how to get the token that `firebase deploy` command required?

Comment: @whuhacker you need to specify GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS before running firebase deploy command

Answer (score 8):

This works:

```
$> gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ./secrets.json --iam-account=<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>

$> export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./secrets.json"

$> firebase deploy --project <PROJECT_ID>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use the refresh token of a Google account (service account or otherwise) that has access to Firebase roles, and set it to the `FIREBASE_TOKEN` environment variable.

For example I use Cloud Build (which has an associated service account that is already logged into `gcloud`) and then set `FIREBASE_TOKEN` to the output of 
`gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`.

Comment: Thanks for that suggested solution. Based on that I created a dedicated build step which I simply wanted to share for others looking into it:

`- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    args: ['-c', 'gcloud auth application-default print-access-token > FIREBASE_TOKEN']`

Comment: @thoutbeckers "service account or otherwise"- how can I obtain refresh token of a service account?

Comment: In my case the service account is already the set account, but in the past I've used the `--impersonate-service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL` flag with `gcloud` for other things. Make sure your the role of your own account is high enough (it needs the `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` permission). If it works you can let me know here and I'll update the answer.