# Login to firebase using gcloud service account

Tags: firebase, gcloud, service-accounts, firebase-cli

I have functions deployed to gcloud functions and i want to configure CI/CD for deploying this functions from gitlab.
To do any operations from gitlab i need to get firebase auth token with

`firebase login:ci`

command.

The problem is that i need to get this token using gcloud service account, which is not displayed in browser, when i run

`firebase login:ci`

I have this service account data (`project_id`, `private_key`, `private_key_id`, etc.)

How should i authorize using this acc?

Comment: Hi, as @Michael Bleigh mentioned, services using ADC first search for credentials within a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.Unless you specifically require ADC to use other credentials (for example, user credentials), you should set this environment variable to point to your service account key file (the .json file downloaded when you created a service account key. Could you please let us know if this solution works for you?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you set an environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as a path pointing to your service account JSON file, the Firebase CLI will automatically pick that up and use it to authorize commands. You don't need to be logged in or provide a `--token` argument when this is the case.

Comment: The problems I had were solved by using the absolute path when setting the environment variable. If you're using a CI environment, this is how to do so: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$(realpath your-authentication-key.json)`

Answer (score 11):

If anyone finds this and is wondering how to do it on CircleCI, this worked for me.

1. Generate a json file key for you service account in the GCP Console
2. Set the json to a CircleCI environment variable at the org level or the project level

   - We use one at the org level called `GSA_KEY`
3. In your workflow config, before you run the firebase command, run this command:

   - `echo echo $GSA_KEY > "$HOME"/gcloud.json`
4. Then run your `firebase deploy` command, first setting the path to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

The deployment run looks like:

```sh
steps:
  - checkout
  - run:
      name: Create SA key JSON
      command: echo $GSA_KEY > "$HOME"/gcloud.json
  - run:
      name: Deploy to Firebase
      command:
        GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="$HOME"/gcloud.json firebase deploy [project specific stuff]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use command:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account xyz@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com  --key-file=/path/to/file.json --project=project-id
```

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/file.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

in Bash

run the following commands 1 and 2 in order

1. export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/file.json"

"/path/to/file.json" -- the location of the file where the service account json file is saved.

2. npx firebase-tools deploy --json

Do not forget to use the right project when deploying like
firebase use dev or
firebase use qa

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Added the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json
2. firebase deploy --non-interactive # needed to bypass any prompts that might stall out a CI script.

You can also set the value of the Environment variable to be the JSON in the key file.