# Firebase hosting deploy with serviceaccount fails with 403

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to deploy a Firebase hosted project with a Service Account (that I created myself, not one provided by Google/Firebase as default) via a pipeline (Gitlab, but that shouldn't matter for this issue).

When I run the following command locally (same happens in the pipeline):

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/serviceaccount.json" firebase deploy --only hosting
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
=== Deploying to 'my-firebase-project'...

i  deploying hosting

Error: HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission
```

The `--debug` does not provide any more details, other than the 403. I've set the following roles to the serviceaccount:

- Firebase Hosting Admin
- Firebase Rules Admin
- API keys viewer

Deploying the rules (using `--only firestore`) works without issues. I've read the documentation about the roles of [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-product#hosting), but assigning these don't work either.

Does anyone know which roles I'm missing?

**Note:** a service account is used here to do a deployment, so any `firebase login` / `firebase logout` actions won't have any effect. See [Login to firebase using gcloud service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053919/login-to-firebase-using-gcloud-service-account) for details.

Comment: I've also posted a request with Firebase support. This may be a bug in the `firebase` cli.

Comment: Firebase support said that I should add `Firebase Admin` in order to deploy to Firebase Hosting with a serviceaccount, but that doesn't work either. I'll update here if I get another response from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Firebase support, I was pointed to the *Deploying to Firebase* [page](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase#required_iam_permissions), which provides an enumeration of all required roles. To sum it up here:

1. Cloud Build Service Account
2. Firebase Admin
3. API Keys Admin

I was missing the first one, which resulted in this error. Hope that this'll help others as well!

Answer (score -2):

You have to add the role at the cluster level using `oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-reader system:serviceaccount:myproject:default`

Comment: `oadm` is not related in any way to Firebase. How would this solve the problem?